# Automatic Mysql updates

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Is it possible to have mysql automatically update a field in a table once a certain number is reached?

I have a table called `badges` and it has these fields

```
ID,name,image,level, percent
```

Can i make it so that if the percent field gets to a certain number (for example 50) , the level field is updated to 2 .

I think this would be a trigger ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do several things.

**In syntax**

You can even write it in the syntax, allthough the value is not changed in the table then just something else is displayed. Like this

```
SELECT  ID, 
        name,
        image, 
        CASE WHEN percent > 50 THEN 2 ELSE level END AS Level, 
        percent FROM....
```

**In Trigger**

After each insert you have to count the value and then update accordingly. Maybe something like this

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS databasename.badges_AUPD$$
USE databasename$$
CREATE TRIGGER `badges_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `badges` FOR EACH ROW

// Added this line from Andreas Wederbrands answer which is the correct way

set new.level := case when percent < 50 then 0
                    when percent < 75 then 1
                    else 2;
    $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**In Stored Procedures**

You could simply schedule a event that executes the Stored Procedure. This however wont work if you really need the value to be changed once it reaches 50.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateLevel` ()
BEGIN
UPDATE badges set level=2 WHERE precentage > 50;
END
```

Comment: getting this error - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: Delete the TRIGGER you just created and create the same on but with `AFTER INSERT`. You need this on `AFTER UPDATE` because when the row is new and inserted it automatically has a level value right?

Comment: No trigger was created . Am i meant to be entering this under the SQL tab ?

Comment: NO on the table of where you want to create the trigger.

Comment: Im in the badges table in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77901/discussion-between-kay-nelson-and-jess).

Answer (score 1):

Derived values are best calculated when read instead of stored, this way you can change your thresholds whenever you want

```
select ID, 
       name,
       image,
       case when percent < 50 then 0
            when percent < 75 then 1
            else 2
            as level, 
       percent
  from some_table;
```

Your other alternative is to set the value for level in a trigger

```
create trigger set_level
before insert on some_table
for each row begin
  set new.level := case when percent < 50 then 0
                        when percent < 75 then 1
                        else 2;
end
```

Do the same for `before update`.

You shouldn't recalculate the entire tables levels on the insert/update of just one or a couple of rows.

Comment: you are most right, I forgot that. Would cause heavy updates on each `INSERT`. Tack sa mycket!

Answer (score 0):

Yes can do it with script and it's run and execute by server automatically..

follow this steps:

1) first of all write a code that what you want to update in a database field.

2)set a cronjob for server execute your query itself.

Comment: Okay . I know how to update a field with sql code. I don't know how to update a field when another field reaches a certain point .  Apart from that the cron job seems straight forward .

Comment: Which will be very innefficient and the updates won't happen in realtime :(